# Docker環境下でSpring Securityを有効にした状態でAPIリクエストを処理したい

Tags: docker, spring-boot, spring-security

#### 実現したいこと

dockerコンテナ間通信でSpring Security環境下でcros設定を適用させたい
※[こちら](https://teratail.com/questions/055fv9peszz6na)のサイトでも並行で質問させていただいております。

#### 前提

下図のようにfrontendをvue.js、backendをSpring bootで設定したDockerコンテナを用意し
frontendで受け取ったhttpリクエストをbackendへAPI連携する構成を作成しています。
[image: 環境概要図]

frontendコンテナ側のフレームワークと依存関係

frontendコンテナで立ち上げたwebサーバーにアクセスし、backendコンテナに対してAPIリクエストを送信しようとするとCORS Policyエラーとなる。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080' from origin 'http://localhost:9001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

#### 該当のソースコード

Spring boot側のCROS設定として、mainクラスが記載されているMyappApplication.javaと同階層に設置。

```
package jp.myapp.app;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
public class CrosConfig {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrosConfig.class);

    @Value("${host.url}")
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dbHostName;


    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(hostName));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addExposedHeader("Set-Cookie");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        configSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return new  CorsFilter(configSource);
    }
    
}
```

#### 試したこと

Spring SecurityをOffにした状態では上記の設定で動作しますが、Spring Securityを設定するとCROSエラーとなってしまします。
Docker環境下でSpring Securityを使用するにはどのように設定すればよろしいでしょうか。
ご教授お願いいたします。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

■frontend
フレームワーク：vue.js
APIリクエストライブラリ：axios

■backend
フレームワーク：Spring Boot
パッケージ管理：maven

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/055fv9peszz6na) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0):

おそらく、追加でSpring Security向けに同様の設定を行えば問題は解消すると思われます:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

参考:

- [Spring Security(6.2): CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.2/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title)
- [Spring Boot の CORS 設定を全許可する – 発火後忘失](https://yukihane.github.io/blog/202101/24/spring-boot-cors-permit-all/)

  - 古いバージョンを対象にした記述なので現行バージョンと書き方が異なっています

(ちなみに、CROSではなくCORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)です)